# Why is My WSO2 API Manager Constantly Reaching out to an Endpoint on port 9099 when we don't have a websocket API published?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

As the title suggests, I have an API Manager that is unsuccessfully reaching out on port 9099 multiple times per second and filling up the wso2carbon.log (as seen below)
[image]

I do not have any websocket APIs published so I'm unsure what endpoint it's looking for. We tried commenting out the ws_endpoint in the apim.gateway.environment block of the deployment.toml but that did not produce any perceptible changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I have noticed whenever I shut down API manager, this stack trace below appears. It is failing to destroy this Inbound endpoint, and then tries to recreate it after the service starts, but says it already exists (so any changes on the websocket endpoint configs do nothing)
[image]

Comment: what is the version of APIM?

Comment: Version is 3.1.0 @Pubci

Comment: If you don't have any websocket API, you can remove the files in repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/inbound-endpoints location

Comment: Better to take a backup when removing the files

Comment: Is there any health check configured for the websocket port?

Comment: If the requests are coming to websocket port, you can get these log lines

Comment: I took backups of those files so I'll have to see how that affects it the next time I am able to restart the wso2 service. You'll have to forgive me, which cmd are you referring to to check the logs on the port?